Help understanding gauge symmetry and principal bundles
i'm diving into gauge theories and i'm having a hard time understanding the concept of Gauge symmetry.
What i understand is: gauge symmetry is the invariance of a field theory under a certain family of transformations called gauge transformations who form a Lie group called the gauge group.
these theories require a principal bundle description. my firtst intuition to this was that since we allow transformations to be local (i.e. depend on position) we had a symmetry group for every point $x$. for example, if we have $ SO(3) $ rotational symmetry for any point $x$ we have attached a copy of $ SO(3) $ whose rotation matrices $ R_i(x) $ depend on $x$. is this true?
i'm confused since the Wikipedia article "Gauge Theory" states explicitly that

In order to adequately describe physical situations in more complex theories, it is often necessary to introduce a "coordinate basis" for some of the objects of the theory that do not have this simple relationship to the coordinates used to label points in space and time. (In mathematical terms, the theory involves a fiber bundle in which the fiber at each point of the base space consists of possible coordinate bases for use when describing the values of objects at that point.) In order to spell out a mathematical configuration, one must choose a particular coordinate basis at each point (a local section of the fiber bundle) and express the values of the objects of the theory (usually "fields" in the physicist's sense) using this basis. Two such mathematical configurations are equivalent (describe the same physical situation) if they are related by a transformation of this abstract coordinate basis (a change of local section, or gauge transformation).

this would imply that said fiber bundle is the frame bundle $ LM $ and its gauge transformations are just coordinate changes/Lorentz transformations.
which one is correct? is the bundle a general $G$-bundle or the frame bundle?
also i don't exactly remember where i read that the generators of the lie algebra of the gauge group produce a set of fields called gauge fields that ensure the local symmetry isn't broken.
an example would be that of the scalar field. which has a global $ U(1) $ symmetry, by demanding this symetry to be local the lagrangian
$$ \mathcal{L} =  \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu} \bar{\phi} -   m^2 \phi \bar{\phi} $$
doesn't satisfy the symmetry anymore so in order to fix this we change the derivative to a covariant one with Yang-Mills field $ A_\mu $ which i think would be the gauge field.
why is it that we need to change the derivative to a covariant one in order to solve the problem of local symmetry breaking?
also, why are we interested in local symmetries to begin with?
i think that's all for now. i'm very lost and couldn't find any answers to my questions so any help is welcome
